# GoogleCloudMessaging - callbacks all gone in the new API?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm in the process of converting a working GCM Client app which uses the now deprecated (after only a short time in existence) classes **GCMRegistrar** and **GCMBaseIntentService** to the newer **GoogleCloudMessaging** API.

It appears to me that the deprecated callbacks `onRegistered()` and `onUnregistered()` have no new equivalents and that there is now no handshaking on the `unregister()` method in the new API.

Am I correct in this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, at least as far as I can tell.

FWIW, I have [before](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClient) and [after](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClients) versions of a project demonstrating the sort of migration, including partial quasi-backports of `GCMRegistrar` and `GCMBaseIntentService`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall study these. I'm undertaking this port with very little enthusiasm, as it's work which gives me no additional benefits or added functionality as far as I can see. Your before/after examples might make the job less tedious.

Comment: @NickT: Yeah, this felt to me like a gratuitous "lets add a dependency on the Play Services SDK" move as much as anything else. In particular, it's unclear why they deprecated their original client JAR, then didn't replace it with anything, since we still need most of that logic anyway. That's why I undertook the backport, ripping code from the old JAR and amending it to speak to the new `GoogleCloudMessaging` API.

Comment: I think it might have been to remove the requirement for having a Google account on the machine/emulator. I must have made at least 6 Mickey Mouse/Donald Duck type accounts for my emulators which will just lie around clogging up their databases.